# Eliminating Middle Initials from a name string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to eliminate middle initials whenever I come across them in a table:

For example if I have John D Doe, I want my query to return John Doe. Here is my query.

```
declare @Name varchar(100);

select @Name = 'James D Doe';

select left(@Name, len(@Name)-charindex(' ', @Name,0))+' '+right(@Name, charindex(' ', @Name,0));
```

Right now my query is returning the full string. How do I strip off the Middle initials whenever I come across them? My desired output is James Doe.

Comment: What about a name like "Charlie Van Der Wonder"?  This is one reason data models often have multiple columns (firstname, middleinitial lastname for example)

Comment: And also I have a family member with multiple initials of the form "Jon D C Doe" which is sometimes written "Jon D. C. Doe" or "Jon Doe III" - there are  other cases as well to consider.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I do understand that but I will like to get and answer to this specific question. Thanks

Comment: For just an answer to this specific question, `STUFF(@name, PATINDEX('% [A-Z] %', @name), 2, '')`  should work. For an answer to the problem of different names with different styles, you're going to have to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your specific use case where you only have a single middle name (or initial):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(@Name, ' ', '')) = LEN(@Name) - 2
THEN
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, 0)),
           SUBSTRING(@Name,
                     CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, 0) + 1) + 1,
                     LEN(@Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, CHARINDEX(' ', @Name, 0) + 1)),
ELSE @Name
END
```